# Implement hardware instancing on Directx11

Tags: c++, directx-9, voxel

I'm a total beginner with Directx/3D programming. I need help with implementing hardware instancing on Directx 11. I'm trying to render multiple cubes on the screen, to create some sort of Minecraft-esque voxel engine. The problem is, I don't know where to start to achieve this. This is how my "render frame" function looks:

```
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    D3DXMATRIX matView, matProjection;
    D3DXMATRIX matFinal;

    // create a view matrix
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 9.0f, 24.0f),   // the camera position
        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),    // the look-at position
        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));   // the up direction

// create a projection matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
        (FLOAT)D3DXToRadian(45),                    // field of view
        (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
        1.0f,                                       // near view-plane
        100.0f);                                    // far view-plane

// create the final transform
    matFinal = matView * matProjection;

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

    // clear the depth buffer
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(zbuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

    // select which vertex buffer to display
    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(pIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // select which primtive type we are using
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // draw the Hypercraft
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(pCBuffer, 0, 0, &matFinal, 0, 0);
    devcon->DrawIndexed(24, 0, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Notice that there's a single vertex buffer containing the verteces of a cube, and index buffer containing its indeces. I want to render many (5000+) cubes on the screen at once on a single draw call, without performance issues, so I know instancing is the way to go, but I don't know how to implement it in my code. What changes do I need to do to my code in order to display multiple instances of the cube?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps in DX11.  But these are the high level notes.

1. You will need to update your Vertex Shader signature to include the additional instance fields, off the top of my head, you basically set them to slot 1 rather 0, and align the bytes in a manner similar to creating your vertex shader vertices definition.  Extra note here is to ensure if you feed a matrix in, you know whether its column or row major.
2. Update your vertex shader to reflect the additional instance fields you defined in your signature.
3. Set your instance buffer to slot 1 or whatever n value you have defined for your instance against.  It's important that the slot you set matches your definition.
4. From the looks of it, you will need to call DrawIndexInstanced, passing in the count of instances as well.

Note: Use a matrix for your cubes if they need to be aligned.  You will incur a draw penalty not on the CPU side but on GPU, its just life.  But it is by far the most efficient way to call.